# How to add a JSON object to a variable in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do this.

```
var dates = {
  start: randomDailyStartDate,
  end: randomDailyEndDate
};

vars.putObject('appSearchString', dates);
```

But in request, it goes like [object object]

For a big payload object, I am having to create multiple variables for each key. How do I avoid that and create one variable with the whole object in it? I am using JS with JSR223 PreProcessor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function on your object in order to convert it to a String representation, however this function may or may not be available in your JavaScript engine implementation.

Moreover [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so you could consider migrating to Groovy and refactoring your code like:

```
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def start = new Date()
    def end = start + 4.hours
    def dates = [:]
    dates.put('start', start.format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'))
    dates.put('end',  end.format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'))
    vars.put('appSearchString', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(dates).toPrettyString())
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)